# Equal size for multiple panels with different y-axis scales in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I have multiple variables of a time series that differ in their scales. I want to plot each variable over time in a single-page, and each plot will have its own y-axis. 
Seems to be easy, but I have a symmetry problem, since the plots that have higher values for y-axis were flattened to the right compared with the ones with smaller values for y-axis. Another problem with the panel size appeared when I decided to keep the x-axis only in two plots. These panels became more flattened than the others.

I'm relatively new to lattice and I have searched a lot with no success. First I tried to arrange the plots with `grid.arrange`, but I can't modify a specific panel with this function. So I tried to arrange plots with `print` and then use `panel.widths` and `panel.heights`. but it doesn't give the exactly equal size for all panels.
Any suggestions to get multiple panels with equal sizes considering different y-axis and x-axis presence/absence? Example below:

```
#Data
a<-c(1058.2557,821.2002,1004.5201,296.8243,374.3730,746.0718,954.6511,264.7352)
b<-c(100,60,40,36,42,32,42,32)
c<-c(116.610418,164.462337,47.862511,12.613479,4.253702,39.868584,21.591731,6.037917)
d<-c(4,10,3,2,1,5,11,13)
e<-c(20,30,10,50,21,60,20,70)
est1<-c("16:00","19:00","22:00","01:00","04:00","07:00","10:00","13:00")
newest1<-factor(est1,levels=unique(est1))

mysettings<-list(layout.heights=list(top.padding=-1,bottom.padding=-1),
layout.widths=list(right.padding=-2))

plo1<-barchart(a~newest1,scales=list(x=list(alternating=0)),par.settings=mysettings)
plo2<-barchart(b~newest1,scales=list(x=list(alternating=0)),par.settings=mysettings)
plo3<-barchart(c~newest1,scales=list(x=list(alternating=0)),par.settings=mysettings)
plo4<-barchart(d~newest1,scales=list(x=list(rot=45)),par.settings=mysettings)
plo5<-barchart(e~newest1,scales=list(x=list(rot=45)),par.settings=mysettings)

trellis.device(windows, height=6, width=7)
print(plo1, split=c(1,1,2,3),more=T)
print(plo2, split=c(2,1,2,3),more=T)
print(plo3, split=c(1,2,2,3),more=T)
print(plo4, split=c(2,2,2,3),more=T)
print(plo5, split=c(1,3,2,3),more=F)
```

Comment: @Henrik I think it was supposed to be `e` rather than `f`. I went ahead and changed it. It runs without error now.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you wouldn't layout related plots like that in lattice. You would typically use a grouping variable. For this to work, you need all your data in one data.frame

```
dd <- data.frame(make.groups(a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d,e=e), newest1=newest1)
```

And to make things look a bit nicer i'll define a custom axis function

```
axis.yout<- function(side, ...) { 
    if(side %in% c("left", "right")) {
        if (panel.number() %% 2 == which(c("right","left")==side)-1) {
            panel.axis(side = side, outside =TRUE)
        }
    } else {
        axis.default(side = side, ...)
    }
}
```

now I plot with

```
barchart(data~newest1 | which, dd, layout=c(2,3), 
    scales=list(alternating=T, y=list(relation="free")),
    par.settings=list(layout.widths=list(right.padding=5, axis.panel = c(1, 0))),
    axis=axis.yout
)
```

which result in

[image]

which all share a common x-axis while allowing for free and independently labeled y-axis. And the spacing/passing is all consistent because we used a single call to lattice. Normally you wouldn't bother with a custom axis function like this, but when the scales relation is "free", lattice gets a bit grumpy about alternating labels.

Comment: Great that you fullfilled my promise ("I am sure...")! +1

Comment: I didn't want to make you a liar @Henrik ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am sure someone will post a nice `lattice` solution. Meanwhile, you may consider a `ggplot` alternative.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
```

First, collect your vectors in a data frame, and reshape data from a wide to a long format:

```
df <- data.frame(newest1, a, b, c, d, e)   
df2 <- melt(df, id.var = "newest1")
```

Plot the data in separate `facets`, one facet for each of the original vectors (which in the `melt`ed data ("df2") appear as different levels of the "variable" variable). We allow independent ("`free`") y axis `scales` in each facet:

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = newest1, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]